# Excel complex conditional on multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm newer to writing scripts for Excel and trying to figure out how to write a formula which does the following.

Given a dataset such as below, figure out if any hamburgers with the exact same project name have been shipped. There can be multiple rows for a given hamburger in a single project. However, if no rows indicate that a hamburger within a single project has been shipped, then the final result should be the number 0. If at least one row for a single hamburger project contains the status "shipped", then the final result should be the number 1.

Consider the following table. The script I'm trying to write would find Project B and indicate all lines next to it with a result number 0. However, Projects C & D would have "1" next to them for all their respective rows.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Fry</td>
    <td>New</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Fry</td>
    <td>Prep</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Fry</td>
    <td>Shipped</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Hamburger</td>
    <td>New</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Hamburger</td>
    <td>Prep</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>Hamburger</td>
    <td>New</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>Hamburger</td>
    <td>Prep</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>Hamburger</td>
    <td>Shipped</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>Hamburger</td>
    <td>New</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>Hamburger</td>
    <td>Prep</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>Hamburger</td>
    <td>Shipped</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried to write an If statement but I'm absolutely clueless on how to even start. It went

```
=if(AND(MATCH(B2,B:B,0),  AND(MATCH("Shipped",C:C,0)), 1, 0)
```

which I realize is probably strange as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple countifs should getr the result; wrap a sign function around it to get one or zero.

```
=SIGN(COUNTIFS(A:A, F2, B:B, G2, C:C, H$1))
```

[image]